# Doubt about the spectrum of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, differential-operators

I consider the Laplacian operator
$$A=-\Delta$$ in the domain $$H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$$ where it is selfadjoint. We know that its spectrum is $[0,+\infty)$. Now I want to consider the restriction of $A$ to a given subspace of $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. What can I say about the spectrum of this restriction?

Comment: Do you have some kind of space in mind? Because in this way is too general to make a classification.

Comment: I need the restriction on the subspace of function antysimmetric. I think that I can solve the problem using HVZ theorem, but I wanted to know if there was some general result on the spectrum of restriction.